# Can I create a plugin in kibana which give me "Download as csv option" in the menu of the widgets inside the dashboard of kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-plugin

I need to make a plugin that is similar to the x-pack "reporting plugin". X-pack is paid but I need to make this for free.

Any help from anyone on how to do it?  Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

CSV exports is free for everyone with the [Basic version](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) of Elasticsearch:

[image]